# Refusing to paste formula with IFERROR

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I don't know why, but apparently and ironically VBA gives an error on this line.

```
Range("OptionH").Formula = "=IFERROR((RC[1]-RC[-1])/RC[1];0)"
```

When I only keep the formula
    `"=(RC[1]-RC[-1])/RC[1]"`
there is no problem. So it must have something to do with the iferror.

Comment: are you located somewhere that the list separator is (`;` not `,`)?

Comment: ...also, what happens if you try: `=IF(ISERROR((RC[1]-RC[-1])/RC[1]),0,(RC[1]-RC[-1])/RC[1])`

Comment: Ashleedawg is right, you just need to change the ";" to "," in your code (VBA just takes "," in codes)

Comment: @Pierre44 -- I only recently learned that some parts of the world use the semicolon instead of the comma so that may not be the issue :-)

Comment: Some part of the world use semicolon in spreadsheets. In VBA everybody use colon.

Comment: @MarcinSzaleniec ohhhhh ok thanks -- Yeah *berwt*, do the first thing I said!

Comment: @MarcinSzaleniec -- except this isn't VBA, he's using VBA to enter a formula on a spreadsheet

Comment: Another possible issue: is 'Range("OptionH")` referring to multiple cells?   In the immediate window (`CTRL+G` from VBA), type `?Range("OptionH").Address` and share with us what it returns.

Comment: @ashleedawg I am still sure that it works just changing the ";" into a "," 
I have an excel with semicolon and I use "," in VBA for his formula otherwise I get the same issue as him.

Comment: @ ashleedawg: Believe me. I used to work on Excel that have ";" as separator. Stil, in VBA's Application.Worksheetfunction colons were expected.

Comment: Well, I can confirm now that this little dot made the difference. I used the "," in VBA now and it returned the ";" in Excel. Thanks, all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what is going on do the following small trick, translating the formula to VBA:

- Write the formula in Excel, thus it works ok.
- Select the cell with the formula.
- Run this code:

---

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.Formula
    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula

End Sub
```

---

Take a look at the immediate window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.